# Having trouble linking my .css file to my html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having trouble linking my CSS file to my HTML file despite being in the same folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Intro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index-css.css">
</head>

<style>
    h2 {
        color: palevioletred;
    }
</style>



<body>

    <!--Inline styles - BAD! -->
    <!-- <h1 style="color: purple"> Hello World </h1>
    <button style="background-color : palegreen">I AM BUTTON</button> -->
    <h2>I AM A NEW COLOUR</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

<! -- css file: index-css.css -->

```
h2 {
    color: indigo;
}
```

<! -- so I'd like to know why the css file is not properly integrated with the html file despite both files being in the same folder? I am brand new to coding and just finished with html lesson and now started css concepts and learning css before going into JavaScript. Can someone explain to me what's going on? -->

Comment: It is being loaded, but `indigo` is being overridden by your `palevioletred` value inside the document. They're the same selector – `h2` – and the one in the document comes after the `<link />`, so it "wins" and is applied. Try changing the CSS file's selector to `body h2` to make it "win" instead.

Comment: @Leland - all I did was in the CSS file, type "body" before "h2", saved, and it worked! Thank you! I followed the Udemy Web Dev bootcamp video and the instructor did not add "body" to his CSS file and I followed exactly his instructions and I expected the same output but it did not happen. Which what made me ask, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Alternatively, try putting your `<style>` block *before* the `<link />` element. This is the cascade: when selectors have the same level of specificity, *the last one wins*. By either increasing the specificity, or changing the order, we can determine which gets applied. `body h2` has a specificity of 2, whereas `h2` is a specificity of 1.

Comment: This will all become more clear as you continue in the bootcamp :) For the future, here's a handy tool to calculate a CSS selector's level of specificity: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: @Leland - I really appreciate you taking the time giving me this advice. This is my first post in StackOverflow and I look forward to connecting and contributing to this wonderful community.